# Can I place admob ads on my quiz app with earning system?

Tags: android, admob

I am building a Quiz app that will allow users to earn points. They can redeem those points into real cash once they reached the minimum threshold. I would like to monetize my app with AdMob ads but I am confused after reading their policy.

"Google ads may not be placed on apps that promise payment or incentives to users who click on ads, surf the web, read emails, or perform other similar tasks. Placing Google ads on such apps may result in invalid impressions or clicks and is therefore prohibited."

Does my app eligible for AdMob?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're ok. As long as the users aren't being paid for doing things that directly earn you money.
It seems these rules are put in place for people who are trying to cheat the system. 
If you're still unsure you can try asking them directly here:
https://support.google.com/adsense/gethelp

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let's see how it goes 

Comment: @Paul - I've similar question. were you able to successfully place Ads without policy violation. Could you also pls share app store link?